# Importing services in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, import, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a utils service I wish to use in my Vue component:

```
  import utils from './utils';

  export default {
    name: 'grid',
    props: {
      'gridInit': { type: Object, require: true },
      'gridDataInit' : { type: Array, required: true }
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        gridData: [],
      }
    },
    created: function(){
       this.gridData = utils.transformRawData(this.gridDataInit, this.gridInit.check);
    },

  }
```

However, I receive:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: utils is not defined"
```

How can I solve the issue? The structuring of my project with utils services is very important to me.

Comment: Seems like a packaging/referencing error, the problem stems from somewhere else, not the code shown above. What's your directory structure like?

Answer (score 0):

This code says that you have declared `utils` as you imported. So that was the declaration part. But what about definition? In definition there is main play happening around for which that declared `utils` is used in code. So I think it creates warning that it is not defined. You should use it via registering like `Vue.use(componentname/pluginname)`. This all should be done in index.js and then should be used in components

Anyhow hope this clears for you!